# Power Plays in the Final Period

Tags: ice-hockey, olympics

After watching the US-Canada Women's gold medal match, where the Canadian's had 30 seconds remaining in a power play following the end of the last period, I have to ask a question. If you know that a shootout is likely, why doesn't one team use their weakest shooter, who would suffer a penalty, to slam into the opposing team's best shooter with the hope of causing a performance-impacting injury? Of course, this would not be a respectable action, but, other than sportsmanship, what reason is there to not field this strategy? Sure the advantage gained for the shootout may be nominal, but even a tiny error in skating or handling can cause a shooter or goalie to miss.

Answer (score 1):

Because:

- Most people have morals.
- Anyone which was ever found to have been involved in this (the players, the coaches, the team management) would immediately receive life bans from the IIHF.
- This would probably also be criminal assault in many jurisdictions.
- Players don't want to start this kind of thing - they could be the next one on the end of an intentional injury.
- Pierre de Coubertin once said something about winning.
- So many more reasons.

Comment: Thanks. Those are all reasons that I agree with but do not explain why it would be a poor strategy. Getting found out would probably be unlikely-many hits are tolerated and certainly, no one would record that they chose that as a strategy, which makes the assault point a stretch (although I agree that this SHOULD count as assault). In some situations, such as the famous Canada-Soviet games, where the tension between the competing countries is high, all of them, this kind of decision may be easy to make. Bitter hatred does throw a wrench in most peoples' moral reasoning.

Comment: Players can also go to jail for this.. [Dino Ciccarelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dino_Ciccarelli) did (for a different kind of assault on the ice, but it's certainly possible).